# Error while trying to use polyval

Tags: matlab, math, precision, floating-point-precision, largenumber

I have the following vector

```
vec = [ 255     0   255     0   255     0   255     0   255     0   255     0   255     0   255     0]
```

*vec 1x16 double*

and using the following command

```
polyval(vec', 256);
```

I get

```
ans = 3.3896e+038
```

but when I try to get back my original vector

```
vec2 = decimal2base(ans, 256)
```

I get

```
vec2 = 255     0   255     0   255     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

and this is clearly not my original vector.

Whats more if again I run `polyval` in this vector

```
polyval(vec2', 256);
```

I get

```
ans=

  3.3896e+038
```

I am not entirely sure what sort of mistake I am making as I know that my conversion functions are ok, so it must be a number precision thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, large numbers. The value `3.3896e+038` is higher than the maximum integer that can be represented by a `double` without loss of accuracy.

That maximum number is 2^53 or

```
>> flintmax('double')
ans =
   9.0072e+15
```

So you are losing accuracy and you cannot reverse the computation.

---

Doing the computations with `uint64` values only:

```
>> pows = uint64(fliplr(0:numel(vec)-1));
>> sum(uint64(vec).*(uint64(256).^pows),'native')
ans =
 18446744073709551615
```

That's about 1.84e+19. Just a *little* different from what you get if you use doubles. But wait... that number [looks familiar](https://www.google.com/search?q=18446744073709551615):

```
>> intmax('uint64')
ans =
 18446744073709551615
```

So, you've maxed out unsigned 64-bit integers too:

```
>> uint64(256).^pows
ans =
  Columns 1 through 5
 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615
  Columns 6 through 10
 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615    72057594037927936      281474976710656
  Columns 11 through 15
        1099511627776           4294967296             16777216                65536                  256
  Column 16
```

When you get above 255^8 or so, you're passing `intmax('uint64')` and you can't manage numbers this large, at least not with MATLAB's built-in data types.

Comment: isn't there a way to get past this?

Comment: @green_leaf As far as I can tell, `polyval(vec', 256)` is very wrong. Try it manually, see updated answer.

Comment: @green_leaf I think you can't even do it manually with 64-bit integers, see another update.

Comment: granted, but what if i tried to do this base256 to decimal and opposite conversion using symbolic math or variable precision numbers, would I have a chance then @chappjc

Comment: @green_leaf Yeah, I suppose so.  [This example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/examples/variable-precision-arithmetic.html) shows computations with up to 780 decimal places of pi and 200 digits of 70!.  If you have the toolbox (I don't) I suppose you could do it. Interesting problem you've got!

Comment: Yeah @chappjc usually all my questions in SO look kind of weird, mostly because I have weird ideas that I want to test out. Just to make sure though, how would I use this method in my case, because in order to convert a vector to decimal or the opposite i need to use a for loop (at least if I use the functions that I created). Also if you don't have the toolbox I recommend the awesome VPA toolbox by John D'Errico that you can easily find in File Exchange.

Comment: @green_leaf With the `.^` and `.*` operators, no loops is needed. See the two commands starting with `pows = ` in the answer. Is that what you mean? Thanks for the tip about the VPA toolbox.

Comment: So to sum it up, if one needs to work with really big numbers (eg >256^8) then he should try either _symbolic computing_ either _Variable Precision Arithmetic_. Thanks @chappjc for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 0):

see if this returns '1':

```
polyval(vec(6:end),256)==polyval(vec2(6:end),256);
```

If so, then it's just a property of '255+1' for that special 'vec'.

Comment: No it returns zero (0) @oligilo.